# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. May i know if there are any trouble shooting points

Tags: lightning, aura, aura-id, js-controller

I have mentioned everything correct, but still i am facing the issue, may i know if there are any trouble shooting points.

Code:

**Component:**

```html
<lightning:combobox name="Select Instance:" aura:id="selctOrg" placeholder="Select an Option" options="{! v.orgList }" value="{!v.selectedOrg }" onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
```

**js controller**:

```js
var selectedSOrg = component.find("selctOrg").get("v.value");
```

**Error is: [Cannot read property 'get' of undefined]**

Below is the code that i had in my controller and helper.

controller:

```
({ doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
helper.fetchSBHelper(component, event, helper);
} })
```

Helper:

```
({ fetchSBHelper : function(component, event, helper) {

    var sOrg = component.find("selctOrg");
    var selectedSOrg = sOrg.get("v.value");
    alert("selectedSOrg"+selectedSOrg); 
}
})
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. On the face of it this looks like it should work. However, I suspect there is more context for the use of lightning:combobox in your component's cmp file that you haven't included here that would help the community help you. Please would you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/314442/edit) your question to add more of the cmp file's detail, specifically showing whether or not the combobox is wrapped in some conditional rendering for example.

Comment: Hi, can you confirm, component is the parameter used in your method(not cmp or others)

Comment: Please edit the question to add more of the component's cmp file content and the entire function containing the selectedSOrg variable initialization, including the passed in parameters.

Comment: Can you share more detail about cmp file? Like are there any conditional rendering around combobox? Because if 'component.find("selctOrg")' cannot find it, it is probably not rendered yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Aura component rendering life cycle, Init event happens when the aura component construction finishes but before rendering child components. In your case, combobox is rendered on the parent component after Init event.

In Init event, combobox has not been rendered when you call `component.find("selectedSOrg")`, it returns undefined.
Consequently, in this line:

```js
var selectedSOrg = sOrg.get("v.value"),
```

the code is trying to get value from an undefined object, that is why it throws exception.

If you put the same code in handleChange js function, it will succeeed.